# What is the best way of reading files outside document root?

Tags: php, macos, apache

I was reading some posts about how to include files outside php root (Apache root). I guess only reading a file is a easier task, may be done with the same solution. But I do not intent to put php or any other script file outside my document root (right now is /Library/WebServer/Documents/), I wish to keep only one root with usual configurations.

But any file outside root is not "visible", it's like my all HD were made just by the root. Php did not return permissions error, it returns file don't exists (or is not a directory error). Is a good security practice, but make my scripts blind! I have a small Intranet an one task I wish to do is to read Safari's favorites file (Bookmarks.plist), also I wish to make a photo viewer, etc.

So I just want to read those files. Is there some hack for this?

EDIT: I was using file_get_contents. Following suggestions, I tried include that stops in permissions issues (probably owner issue). I did a test with a simple file in a Volume (an external HD) and it included just fine. However, I'm thinking in how to deal with data, you know, I was expecting to read the XML to work on it...

EDIT 2: file_get_contents is working with a file in an external HD, so the problem seams to be about permissions/owner file. The info window shows the same users for both files: me, staff and everyone with at least read permission. Maybe there is some "hidden" user... any hacker around?

Comment: Unless open_basedir is enabled, it doesn't need any kind of hack, just a correct filesystem directory/name for the file

Comment: `include()`, unless you're using URLs, e.g. `include('http://....')`, is **NOT** bound by the Apache DocumentRoot settings, and can read/include a file from anywhere on the system's drive, as long as the user that Apache is running under has the rights to reach/read that file.

Comment: I did open the file with TextWrangler, copy the directory/name and put it in the code ... nothing! Outside the root is nowhere for php!

Comment: @Marc B: include get closer - permission denied error. I did change permissions 777 and all users, but still doesn't work.

Comment: Can't change permissions of this file, can't include it, and I'm not sure how to get the data to work on in by including it...

Comment: I think `include` would search the include directories while `file_get_contents` wouldn't. This might explain why `include` worked and `file_get_contents` didn't. If that's the case, try providing an absolute path.

Comment: @Waleed Khan: I'm using only absolute path. This is working: include("/Volumes/Extras/Player1/Eduke32.log");